# SLJ4J Log in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, logging, slf4j

Is it possible to write to a Log file with a slj4j Logger on a maven project?

I imported them and use it with the console which works very good:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());
```

How can i write these loggs also to a file?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ To add context, literally 10 seconds of Googling would give you the answer.

Comment: no, i searched for 40 minutes, but there are only tuts. for log4j logger with files..But if possible, it would be nice if you can send me the link you mentioned.

Comment: That's because SLF4j **isn't** a logger. Hence the name. You need something exactly like Log4j to do the actual logging. In fact, if it's logging to the console now, you must already have a logging framework configured in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: As for a link - given you seem to think that SLF4j is a logger - maybe start with [the FAQ's](https://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#what_is).

Comment: That is the solutions. I am using logback for logging. Did not see this in my start environment.